# Successful ajax request which goes in error callback instead of success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I have an AJAX request which aims at my API but the response goes in to the `error` callback instead of the `success` callback and I don't know why. The status response header is the success status (200). Can you help me please?

I can avoid this issue with the `complete` callback and if the status code is 200 or 400 I will display what I want, but it will not solve the real problem. It's actually what I did but it's not the best solution.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.asaplace.v-labs.fr/users/me/cards/' + numCard,
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'DELETE',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
  },
  success: function() {
    console.log("success");
  },
  complete: function(xhr) {
    alert("carte supprimée avec succès");
    console.log("error");
  },
});
```

The request

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw9p6.png)

Comment: The `error` handler has **three** arguments. How about checking their values _and_ posting them. And there will also be an error in the console.

Comment: If you get a 200 response from the request but logic flows in to the `error` handler it means the response could not be deserialised. In your case, it means it's invalid JSON. Check the console for more information.

Comment: The `complete` callback **isn't** the same as the `error` callback. The `complete` occurs when the request has completed...

Comment: I think you can see 200 in console->network, but success in you ajax call is a mixture of server status code, valid non-empty response as well-formed  json. please post full server answer

Comment: @PaunNarcisIulian it is posted

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If it's an invalid JSON maybe if I use "contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"," ?

Comment: Can you post the error given in from the error callback? This will help the community debug you're problem. You are getting a response but prehaps there is an error in the response.

error: function(err) {
    console.log("error cause", err);
  },

Comment: @B.Sanchez not really, as you're still telling jQuery to expect a valid JSON response, which will not be the case.

Comment: headers looking good. please show response too. also add a complete function: complete: function(xhr, textStatus) { console.log(xhr.status + textStatus);} and post console log. also please disable CORS in your Chrome browser to be sure is not an CORS issue. normally in my PHP code i would add Access-Control-Allow-Methods to header too

Comment: @digital-pollution Hi, I don't know why but I can't edit the post and add the screen of th response

Comment: @PaunNarcisIulian Same problem I can't edit and post a screen but here is the value of xhr.status = 200 and textStatus = parsererror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error the "dataType" was in JSON I put it in xml and it works thank's all for your help